# How does a register remember value?

Tags: computer-architecture, memory-hardware, digital-circuits

So I am studying [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0262640686) great book, and Chapter $3.1$ is about **registers**.

Quoting from this book / chapter:

> A register is a storage device that can "store" or "remember" a value
>   over time, implementing the classical storage behaviour $out(t) = out(t-1)$.

What is mean by:

> the classical storage behaviour $out(t) = out(t-1)$ ?

If **$out(2) = out(1)$** and **$out(1) = out(0)$** how are we ever going to **store** a value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Registers can be thought of as collections of [flip-flops](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_%28electronics%29). These have inputs which, when activated, change the stored value. When not activated, the stored value stays the same. Look at the truth tables in the Wikipedia article.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. My question is more about "classical storage behaviour out(t) = out(t-1)" actually. Title of my question is not very accurate I believe..

Comment: "Classical storage behavior" is what flip-flops implement. The authors of your book tried to convey this information, but clearly failed. Plainly, if it were *always* true that out(t)=out(t-1), then registers would be constant. The only way out is that this behavior actually doesn't always hold. If you want to see how these things actually work, I encourage you to read the Wikipedia article.